# Jquery and Jquery ui

Tags: jquery

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to do an app in Apache Cordova. I have installed Jquery 2.2, but when I try to install also Jquery.ui, I'm not able to find a compatible version. The one proposed needs Jquery >=1.4.4 && < 1.6.0. Is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just include link to jQuery UI from CDN?

Comment: use jQuery migrate `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-migrate`

Comment: which version of jqueryui??

Comment: RRR: jquery migrate is for old versions. 2.2 is the one I'm using.

Comment: Vanojx1: I'm trying to install whatever jquery-ui version that is compatible with jquery 2.2

Comment: Justinas. When I search for a jQuery UI, I'm not able to find any version that is compatible with jQuery 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me here:
https://zohodiscussions.com/jquery/topic/installing-compatible-version
Thanks anyway!